# What do the methods do in this Java program?

Tags: java, methods

I'm confused as to what methods do exactly, so I was hoping for someone to explain the concept to me with this example program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class programB {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String filename;
      String total="";
      String c = "";
      String size = "";
      int num1=0, num2=0;
      char ch;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you want to read data from:"); 
      filename=keyboard.next(); 

      Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));

      while (fromFile.hasNext()) {
         String type = fromFile.next();

         ch = fromFile.next().charAt(0);
         num1 = fromFile.nextInt();
         if (type.equals("rectangle")) {
            num2 = fromFile.nextInt();
         }
         System.out.print(type + " ");
         System.out.print(ch + " ");
         System.out.print(num1 + " ");
         if (type.equals("rectangle")) {
            System.out.print(num2);
        }
         System.out.println();
         if (type.equals("rectangle")){
            rectangle(ch,num1,num2);

         }
         if (type.equals("triangle")){
            triangle(ch, num1);
         }

      }


   }
   /** Draw a rectangle of the specified width and height
    @param c the character that creates the drawing
    @param height the height of the rectangle
    @param width the width of the rectangle
*/
   public static void rectangle(char c, int height, int width){

      for (int i=1; i<=height; i++) {
         System.out.println();
         for (int a=1; a<= width; a++) {
            System.out.print(c);
     }

  }
  System.out.println();

   // put statements here to display a rectangle on the screen using
   // character c and the width and height parameters
   }



/** Draw a right triangle.
@param c the character that creates the drawing
@param size the height and width of the triangle
*/

   public static void triangle(char c, int size){
      for (int i=1; i<=size;i++) {
         for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.print(c);
         }
         System.out.println();

      // put statements here to display a triangle on the screen using
      // character c and the size parameter
      }
   }
 }
```

What are the methods for and what do they do? I've tried researching it online and I've been studying my textbook but I'm still really confused by the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that accompanies the methods does a decent job of explaining what they do, I think. The `rectangle()` method, when called with parameters '-', 3, and 4, will "draw" a rectangle 3 dashes high and 4 wide in the console where the program is run:

```
----
----
----
```

The `triangle()` method is similar; when called with '-' and 3, you'll get a shape like this:

```
-
--
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods, at a basic level, are ways of writing code that you can use multiple times. Methods in Java allow you to define certain actions within your code.

Think of it this way: you know how to draw a triangle, right? So if I told you, "go draw a triangle," you'd know exactly what to do. I *wouldn't* have to say, "put your pencil on a piece of paper and draw a short line, then without picking your pencil up, draw another line, then draw a final line connecting where your pencil is now to the point where you started." That's a whole lot of instructions, so let's just say, whenever I want you to draw a triangle, I'll just say, `triangle()`. Similarly, let's do the same for `rectangle()`.

But what if this got a little more complicated? Instead of just telling you, "draw a triangle," I said, "draw a triangle using ASCII characters with a certain height and a certain width," how much harder could that be? It's actually very simple - you need to know three different things: the `character`, the `height`, and the `width`. Once you have those, you know exactly what to do.

And that's exactly what your code is doing when you call `triangle()` and `rectangle()` - you are passing in three parameters into each of them and your code draws a triangle and a rectangle. And you can do this as many times as you want.